# How to avoid getting null elements in list while collecting and grouping JPA Tuple to Map in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream, refactoring, jpql, collectors

I have following JPQL statement:

```sql
select e as entity, c.type as config_type 
from Entity e 
         left join Config c on e = c.entity 
where c.type = (select t from Type t where t.name = 'SHOP')
```

I want to collect this result to Map grouping by `Entity`. The value of map, should be List of config types. This list can be also empty if `Entity` doesn't have any config specified. I have already wrote some method which accomplishes the task:

```java
public Map<Entity, List<ConfigType>> getGroupedEntityToConfigTypesMap() {
    return em.createNamedQuery(Entity.NQ_GET_ENTITY_TO_CONFIG_TYPE, Tuple.class)
        .getResultStream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            tuple -> ((Entity) tuple.get("entity")),
            Collectors.mapping(tuple -> ((ConfigType) tuple.get("config_type")),
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list ->
                    list.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList())))
        ));
}
```

From my point of view, it doesn't look so good because while collecting values, I have to iterate one more time through every List and check if this list doesn't contain only null value, thus it is not so efficient.

Is there any better way to collect `Tuple` to `Map` with groupingBy more efficient and elegant than now? The goal is to collect also those entries which doesn't have any Configs but it should be mapped to empty list instead of `Lists.of(null);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to check out `Collections.filtering`. I tried to incorporate it into your solution and came up with a little bit more concise and efficient solution. But I have not tested it yet, sorry. Also note, that I returned the filtered objects as a `Set` instead of a `List`. Feel free to keep going with the `List` if that fits your need best. And please hit me up if it worked or you have any other questions.

```
Stream.of(tuple)
        .collect(groupingBy(
            record -> (tuple.get("entity")),
            mapping(record -> (tuple.get("config_type")),
                Collectors.filtering(Objects::nonNull, Collectors.toSet()))
        ));
```